# How to format the online source citations and the author biography in ieeetran inside "thebibliography" tag?

Tags: ieeetran

[image: Online Reference and bio]

[image: Conference Reference]

What should I write inside \begin{thebibliography}{}
                           \end{thebibliography} 
For online reference and conference reference [include all]. Reference number is also alphabetically sorted. I use class IEEETran. And at the end author bio format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Would you mind posting a link to the (compiled) document you have in mind. Eliminating pointless guess-work is always appreciated.

Comment: Dir you looked here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/

Comment: Yes I visited this site. These is a file called "IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf" . I want .tex file of that pdf file.

Comment: I wrote down what I need.

Comment: Thank you for improving the question. Are you using a `bib` file for your references or manually adding them by typing yourself?

Comment: As far as the TeX sources go, from the [author's website](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/): "People sometimes ask for this because they think that the HOWTO code will provide some good examples of usage. Trust me, it won't. The reason is that a lot of special code must be used to display LaTeX code within a LaTeX document. For this and other reasons, I don't release the HOWTO source code."